# Is there a limit to POST over HTTPS for IIS 7?

Tags: php, iis

I am building a web service in PHP that processes data received from a Windows application through a SOAP request. The Windows application is a bit of a black box but it generates a long stream of messages and then POSTS them as a single SOAP request.

Using HTTP this works and requests sized in multiple Mb's work fine.

Using HTTPS only small requests work larger requests fail with a Internal Server Error 500 and never make it to the PHP web service.

The PHP application itself runs on a W2008 server, under IIS7

Is there a setting that influences this or is there a known limit to HTTPS requests?

Comment: The best thing to do would be looking in the error logs for the detailed message

Comment: rather network protocol issue?

Comment: HI, yes there are request Limits but they are configurable, you should check this link [IIS Request Limit](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits)

Comment: The problem is still unresolved, but we have narrowed it down to a flaky HTTPS library used by the Windows application. It seems to trigger a problem when uploads go over a certain size,sometimes. So this problem was not IIS related.